# Nested sorting with path and filter in Spring Data Elastic Search

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have this piece of code that I need to convert into spring-data-elastic-search.

```
 {
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "size": 10,
  "from": 0,
  "sort": [
    {
      "program.title.descriptions.value.keyword": {
        "order": "asc",
        "nested": {
          "path": "program.title.descriptions",
          "filter": {
            "match": {
              "program.title.descriptions.length": "LONG"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried up to this,

```
SortBuilder sb = SortBuilders.fieldSort(sortBy).order(sortOrder).setNestedSort(new NestedSortBuilder(nestedPath))
```

but I don't know how to add the "filter" part into the SortBuilder. If I try the below,

```
QueryBuilder matchFirst = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().filter(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("program.title.descriptions.length", "LONG"));
sb = SortBuilders.fieldSort(sortBy).order(sortOrder).setNestedSort(new NestedSortBuilder(nestedPath)).setNestedFilter(matchFirst);
```

it would say

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Setting both nested_path/nested_filter and nested not allowed
    at org.elasticsearch.search.sort.FieldSortBuilder.setNestedFilter(FieldSortBuilder.java:213)
```

Any ideas will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the filter inside the nested query. You can try

```
SortBuilder sb = SortBuilders.fieldSort(sortBy).order(sortOrder).setNestedSort(new NestedSortBuilder(nestedPath).setFilter(matchFirst));
```